# Ray Tune | Find optimal network hidden size using PBT

Tags: keras, optimization, hyperparameters, ray, ray-tune

I intend to develop a model to test whether PBT is working correctly or not and want to find the optimal hidden layer size via PBT in ray tune, but the hidden layer sizes found by PBT are not optimal. The results are not even suboptimal. I have selected the stop parameter as Val_loss = 5, but the returned model val_loss is more than 20. Also, it is noticeable that the whole computations for train date (700000,7) and ground truth (700000, 4) are less than 5 minutes (for 1 epoch).

The network is

```
def build_model(self, config):
        [x_acc, x_gyro, mag, x_fs], [quat] = training_date()
        Att_quat = Att_q(quat)
        [self.x_gyro_t, self.x_acc_t, mag, self.fs_t], [q_t] = data_oxiod_test()
        self.Att_quat_t = Att_q(q_t)

        self.x_acc, self.x_gyro, self.x_fs, self.Att_quat = shuffle(
            x_acc, x_gyro, x_fs, Att_quat)
        accl = Input((3))
        gyrol = Input((3))
        fsl = Input((1))

        Acc = Reshape((3, 1))(accl)
        Gyro = Reshape((3, 1))(gyrol)

        ALSTM = LSTM(config["ALSTM"], return_sequences=True)(Acc)
        if config["ALSTM_num"] > 1:
            for i in range(config["ALSTM_num"]-1):
                ALSTM = LSTM(config["ALSTM_%d" % i],
                             return_sequences=True)(ALSTM)
        GLSTM = LSTM(config["GLSTM"], return_sequences=True)(Gyro)
        if config["GLSTM_num"] > 1:
            for i in range(config["GLSTM_num"]-1):
                GLSTM = LSTM(config["GLSTM_%d" % i],
                             return_sequences=True)(GLSTM)

        fsdense = Dense(config["fsdense"])(fsl)

        AG = concatenate([ALSTM, GLSTM], axis=2)
        AG = Dropout(0.2)(AG)
        AG = LSTM(config["AGLSTM"], return_sequences=True)(AG)
        AG = Dropout(0.2)(AG)
        AGDense = Dense(config["AGDense"])(AG)
        AGDense = Flatten()(AGDense)
        AGF = concatenate([AGDense, fsdense], axis=1)
        quat_p = Dense(4, activation="linear")(AGF)
        model = Model(inputs=[accl, gyrol, fsl], outputs=quat_p)
        model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
            learning_rate=config['lr']),
            loss=QQuat_mult,
            metrics=[Quat_error_angle]
        )
        return model
```

And the PBT parameters are as follows

```
perturbation_interval = 6
    pbt = PopulationBasedTraining(
        perturbation_interval=perturbation_interval,
        hyperparam_mutations={
            # "dropout": lambda: np.random.uniform(0, 1),
            "lr": lambda: np.random.uniform(0.00001, 0.1),
            "AGDense": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "AGLSTM": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "ALSTM": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "GLSTM": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "fsdense": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "ALSTM_num": tune.choice([0, 1, 2]),
            "ALSTM_0": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "ALSTM_1": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "GLSTM_num": tune.choice([0, 1, 2]),
            "GLSTM_0": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "GLSTM_1": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
        },
        synch=False,
    )
    resources_per_trial = {"cpu": 4, "gpu": 1}
    tuner = tune.Tuner(
        tune.with_resources(
            BroadModel,
            resources=resources_per_trial),
        run_config=air.RunConfig(
            name="BroadPBT",
            stop={"ErrorAngle": 5}
        ),
        tune_config=tune.TuneConfig(
            reuse_actors=False,
            scheduler=pbt,
            metric="ErrorAngle",
            # mode is a f
            mode="min",
            num_samples=2,



        ),
        param_space={
            "finish_fast": True,
            "batch_size": 500,
            "epochs": 1,
            "dropout": 0.2,
            "lr": lambda: np.random.uniform(0.00001, 0.1),
            "AGDense": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "AGLSTM": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "ALSTM": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "GLSTM": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "fsdense": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "ALSTM_num": tune.choice([0, 1, 2]),
            "ALSTM_0": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "ALSTM_1": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "GLSTM_num": tune.choice([0, 1, 2]),
            "GLSTM_0": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),
            "GLSTM_1": tune.choice(mp.arange(32, 256, 5)),

        },
    )
    pbt_results = tuner.fit()
```

The results are far from the optimal value, have I done anything wrong?

Comment: Your search space is pretty large here for the number of samples (only 2). I would recommend increasing `num_samples` to something like at least 8, fixing learning rate or setting its bounds a little more conservatively (max of 0.1 may be causing problems, something like `"lr": tune.loguniform(1e-5, 1e-2),` might be better). Also, consider reducing the search space (ex: would it make sense for each layer in the same network to have the same size, so you only have to sample once?)

Comment: I would also recommend setting `time_attr="training_iteration", syncj=True` in the PBT config - it'll make sure that every 6 iterations results in a round of perturbation. The asynchronous version may not be perturbing often enough - which means that the search space isn't explored well enough.